# How to create graph with nodes and relationships using single Neo4j query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create a graph

```
  ___A____ 
 /   |    \
AA  AB    AC
```

My query is

```
create 
  a = (:Task {title:"A"}),
  aa = (:Task {title:"AA"}),
  ab = (:Task {title:"AB"}),
  ac = (:Task {title:"AC"}),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(aa),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(ab),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(ac)
return *;
```

But response

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError Type mismatch: a defined with
> conflicting type Path (expected Node) (line 6, column 4 (offset: 125))
> "  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(aa),"
> ^

As far as I understand, only nodes or relationships can be created separately.

How to fix this query? Is it possible? If not, what is the easiest alternative to describe the graph in a query?

Comment: Syntax is (a:Task {title:"A"}). Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with. Thanks for @jose_bacoy

```
create 
  (a:Task {title:"A"}),
  (aa:Task {title:"AA"}),
  (ab:Task {title:"AB"}),
  (ac:Task {title:"AC"}),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(aa),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(ab),
  (a)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(ac)
return *;
```